# UICollectionView scrolling swipe direction on tvOS

Tags: uicollectionview, tvos

I have a collection view in a tvOS project. The cells are fullscreen photos. The view has the default scrolling behaviour: in order to display the next photo, I have to swipe from left to right. This is completely opposite to the “natural” scrolling behaviour used elsewhere in the Apple ecosystem.

This behaviour (swipe left-to-right to display next) makes sense when there’s some apparent focus on the screen, but when there’s just the fullscreen content, it feels completely backwards. Is it possible to change it, swiping right-to-left to display next photo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a suggestions on the [Apple Developer Forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/30714) to use `UIPageViewController` instead. That works, the scrolling direction is as expected.